# R returning impossible values when trying to set up the regression for ROC with multiple curves

Tags: r, regression, roc

[Image of roc data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w0PJ.png)

Hello! I have been trying to plot some pilot data in ROC space but have run into some issue that I suspect is because I am fairly new at this. Specifically, I set my regression up like so:

> `> model1 <- lm(probSame.Same ~ Same.Pitch + same.location + same.syl + same.multi, data = rocdata)

> summary(model1)`

and it returns NAN values (image of output attached)
To give some context: the roc data image breaks down such that each column is the probability of respondents saying 'Same' when the item was the same (its a change detection task), then 'Same' when the pitch was different, 'same' when the location was different, 'same' when the syllable was different, and 'same' when all three of those features had in fact changed. Each row is the confidence level:

1. Sure same
2. Sure + Probably same
3. Sure + Probably + Maybe same
4. Sure + Prob + Maybe Same + Maybe different
5. Sure + Prob + Maybe Same + Maybe different + Probably different

So 1-5 increase and get close to a probability of 1.
Anyway, I am getting the attached output which I think means I have a an uneven number of predictors? The output is the same regardless of whether I use glm() or lm(). When I exclude one of the predictors the regression works, but obviously I need to include it.
Can anyone provide guidance on what is wrong with my setup? Thank you for any advice you can give. [Output of regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wPBK.png)

Comment: You have too many predictors for the amount of data you have.  This is a stats problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: That makes sense. It sounds like I need to search for a more suitable forum for this question. If you have any suggestions I'd appreciate it but thank you for the help already.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment notes, "You have too many predictors for the amount of data you have."

Your model involves 4 predictors that you name, plus an intercept. That's 5 parameter values that need to be estimated. You have exactly 5 observations, so you can fit your current data *exactly* with those 5 parameters. There is no residual error and "no residual degrees of freedom," which in this case is the number of observations minus the number of estimated parameter values.

Thus R isn't returning "impossible" values. It's returning exactly what it should for a saturated model like this.

This is an extreme example of overfitting, in which you do a good (here, perfect) job of modeling your data in a way that probably won't generalize to a new data sample. To avoid overfitting with the variability typically seen in human-subjects research, you typically need about 10-20 observations for *each* predictor in a linear regression or, in binary (logistic) regressions, that many members of the minority class per predictor.

As you talk about ROC values and have a probability as your outcome variable, I assume that you are doing binary-outcome modeling. My guess is that there is a better way to accomplish what you want than your current approach, which seems to be working with some type of already processed data. It's usually best to work with as close to the original data as possible. You might ask another question on this site that describes your project and your data in more detail, to get some ideas for other analysis approaches. Please see the [help center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help) for how to ask a question that might get one or more helpful answers.